# Is there any example For datagridView1.DefaultView.RowFilter using 2 condition.?

Tags: c#, excel

My filter for c# excel for 2 condition im still cant find the solution.And im still searching and learning for datetimepicker for 2 conditon also for c# and Excel(database)

(dataGridView1.DataSource as System.Data.DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("state like '%" + txtName.Text + "%','%" + txtStatus.Text + "%'"); <<<< is this posible? to do for 2 condition.because my second condition dont function?

Comment: The expression you provide for that filter is simply a SQL `WHERE` clause, which is a Boolean expression. How do you usually include multiple conditions in a Boolean expression? Just read a basic SQL tutorial and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Also, you should be using a `BindingSource`. Add a `BindingSource` to your form, bind the `DataTable` to it and then bind it to the grid. You then just set the `Filter` property of that `BindingSource`.